# BASH shell parameter (indirect) expansion

Tags: bash, shell

When I enter `echo ${!BASH*}` in my shell, I get all env vars whose name start with the string "BASH":

```
BASH BASHOPTS BASHPID BASH_ALIASES BASH_ARGC BASH_ARGV BASH_CMDS BASH_COMMAND BASH_LINENO BASH_SOURCE BASH_SUBSHELL BASH_VERSINFO BASH_VERSION
```

The BASH man page is quite discreet about this feature called [shell parameter (indirect) expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). This info (the syntax of this particular globbing mode) must be somewhere but I can't find it.

1. Can I match a string at the end of the variable name?

   But mostly
2. Can I match a string anywhere in the variable name?

   Oh and what would be delightful
3. Can I match **anything** (*) anywhere in the variable name? (basically list any variable inside a for loop, and BTW this exactly what I'm trying to do)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know there is no builtin way to do indirect name expansion with matching at end of name.

Here is a command with which you can do what you want:

```
$ compgen -v | grep -E "HOME$"
```

This will match every variable which name ends in HOME.

By varying the grep part you can match any part of the variable name.

`compgen` is a bash builtin meant to be used in completion scripts. `compgen -v` will list all variable names. `compgen -v BASH` will list the same variables as `echo ${!BASH*}`, but one per line.